# Monitor accumulated disk writes over period of time

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, monitoring

Incremental backups of a Ubuntu Server 20.04 VM are unexpectedly large, and I want to find out why.

Is there a tool that can monitor disk write activity, and show a summary of accumulated writes to the filesystem after an extended period of time (e.g. 24h)? Ideally, I would like to see all files that were written to, sorted by write volume; similar to `ncdu`.

Comment: It's easy to find __files__ modified in the last 24 hours and see their sizes, The whole file is what you're backing up, not just changes. If you change 1 byte of a 100Mb file, the whole 100Mb is backed up. Look at the contents of the incremental, and re-evaluate which files you back up.

Comment: @waltinator The backup happens on the block level of the VM disk using Changed Block Tracking, so only changed parts of files are part of the incremental. Also, the entire disk is encrypted, so it's not easily possible to analyze the backup.